# $.ajax results in 403 forbidden

Tags: php, ajax, javascript, security, plugin-wpml

I am trying to fetch debug information from a piece of javascript, to make it easier to copy the debug information code (if find my self often doing this). However, when I send a request to a page, where the code belongs, I get a 403. If I send a blank request to admin_ajax it works fine (just getting error 400, possibly because no action is defined).

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=sitepress-multilingual-cms/menu/debug-information.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response) {
        var debug_information = $(response).find('#wpml-debug-info textarea').val();

        console.log(debug_information);
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Any reason why? And what I can do to bypass it?

Comment: Can you see the request in your brower's debug console - are the credentials passed properly, is there any error message? Or if you add an 'error' function handler do you get an error message there? Are you definitely logged in as a user with access to that page?

Comment: My gut feeling was that it's rejected because the AJAX call will have an Accepts header expecting JSON, but at first glance I can't find code to do that. However it might be easier to look at the plugin and find a different way to expose the error messages, e.g. through a new REST endpoint.